# Token based authentication in Jwplayer

Tags: jwplayer

does Jwplayer support token-based authentication? I want to play webM files that are hosted on my server that needs token-based authentication. I need to be able to put token in headers. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checked in the code, and it does not support it.